# How to keep language changed even after my app is closed in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using `easy_locatizations` package for changing my language. Whenever I am changing language in my app, it works only before i close and restart my app. In that case, language is set back to english. I am using `provider` for state management and `shared_preferences` for saving my language code and retrieve it when my app starts.

But there is a problem. Whenever I use `notifylisteners()` in a specific function `getLocale()` (see the code below) and then call it inside initState or anywhere else, the function is called infinite times and the screen never loads. I will explain it in detail below.

Inside my main function -

```
runApp(
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (_) => AppLocale(),
      child: MyApp(),
    )
  );
```

MyApp -

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    /*AppLocale locale = Provider.of<AppLocale>(context);
    locale.getLocale();*/
    return Consumer<AppLocale>(
      builder: (buildContext, locale, child) {
        /*locale = Provider.of<AppLocale>(context);
        locale.getLocale();*/
        print("The country code is - ${locale.locale.countryCode}");
        return ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (context) => APIData(),
          child: MaterialApp(
            title: 'Board Plus',
            theme: ThemeData(
              fontFamily: 'Nunito Sans',
              brightness: Brightness.dark,
              textTheme: TextTheme(
                headline1: headingStyle1,
                headline2: headingStyle2,
                headline3: headingStyle3,
                headline4: headingStyle4,
                headline6: bodyText3,
                bodyText1: bodyText1,
                bodyText2: bodyText2,
                button: buttonTextStyle,
                caption: linkStyle,
              ),
            ),
            //themeMode: _themeMode,
            supportedLocales: L10n.all,
            locale: locale.locale,
            localizationsDelegates: //AppLocalizations.localizationsDelegates,
            [
              AppLocalizations.delegate,
              GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
              GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
              GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate
            ],
            // home: SplashScreen(),
            initialRoute: isViewed==0 || isViewed==null ? 'splash' : 'home',//'language',
            navigatorObservers: <NavigatorObserver>[observer],
            routes: {
              'home': (context) => AuthenticationWrapper(),
              'splash' : (context) => SplashScreen(),
              'language' : (context) => LanguageSelectionScreen(val: 0,),
            },
            scaffoldMessengerKey: scaffoldMessengerKey,
            navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Here is my app_locale.dart -

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class AppLocale extends ChangeNotifier {
  Locale? _locale;

  set locale(Locale value) {
    _locale = value;
  }

  Locale get locale => _locale ?? Locale('en');

  /*getCode() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    print("Shared pref initiated");
    String code = prefs.getString("code")??"en";
    return code;
  }*/

   getLocale() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    print("Shared pref initiated");
    String code = prefs.getString("code")??"en";
    print("Received code - $code");
    Locale newLocale = Locale(code);
    if(newLocale == Locale('bn')) {
      _locale = Locale('bn');
    } else if(newLocale==Locale('gu')){
      _locale = Locale('gu');
    } else if(newLocale==Locale('en')){
      _locale = Locale('en');
    } else if(newLocale==Locale('pa')){
      _locale = Locale('pa');
    }
    notifyListeners();
    print("Finally code is - ${_locale?.countryCode}");
  }

  void changeLocale(Locale newLocale, String code) async {
    if(newLocale == Locale('bn')) {
      _locale = Locale('bn');
    } else if(newLocale==Locale('gu')){
      _locale = Locale('gu');
    } else if(newLocale==Locale('en')){
      _locale = Locale('en');
    } else if(newLocale==Locale('pa')){
      _locale = Locale('pa');
    }

    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.setString("code", code);
    print("Saved code is  - ${prefs.getString("code")}");
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

As you can see in this file, i have defined two functions, I am using chageLocale in a page to change my language, which is working fine. But whenever I use `getLocale()`, I see those print statement inside the function `getLocale` being printed infinitely in my console, which mean for whatever reason, this function is executing infinitely. And this problem only exists if I use changeNotifier().

Now, you can see in MyApp, the commented part is where I called the function and got the result.

In one of my page `ViewProfiles()` (one of the initial screens in MyApp), I tried to call the function inside my `initState` and same thing occured and my page never loaded because of this. And if I don't use `notifyListeners()`, my language doesn't change after closing and restarting the app.

```
   @override
  void initState() {
    profileList = fetchProfileList();
    getToken();
    selected_id = -1;
    Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
      AppLocale locale = Provider.of<AppLocale>(context);
      locale.getLocale();
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```

Comment: Why do you use "Future.delayed" ?

Comment: @MCB because I can't directly access context in initState.

Comment: hmmm I don't think this is necessary... I use Provider.of(context, listen:false).... a lot of times, without any problem.... have u tried to remove the delay?

Comment: Yeah, at first I used without delay and it gave me an error, that's why I searched and found out and then used delayed.

Answer (score 0):

If you call a provider-function in initState it is important to NOT listen to changenotifiers...

Instead of:

```
AppLocale locale = Provider.of<AppLocale>(context);
localse.getLocale();
```

try to use this:

```
Provider.of<AppLocale>(context, listen:false).getLocale();
```

Comment: Nah, still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and using a constructor in my ChangeNotifier was the answer:

I used _loadPreferredLocale() in the `class constructor` to get the locale from my shared_preferences and deal with async process it brings

```
class LocaleProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  Locale _prefLocale = const Locale('NULL');
  Locale get locale => _prefLocale;

  LocaleProvider() {
    _loadPreferredLocale();
    print("PREF LOCALE: $_prefLocale");
  }

  void _loadPreferredLocale() async {
    print("Recalling Preferred Locale");
    var prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String languageCode = prefs.getString('AppInfo_DefLocale') ?? 'en';
    print("BEFORE RECALLING: $_prefLocale");
    print("Stored Locale: $languageCode");
    _prefLocale = Locale(languageCode);
    print("AFTER RECALLING: $_prefLocale");

    notifyListeners();
  }

  void setLocale(Locale newlocale) async {
    print(printSignifier + "Setting Preferred Locale " + newlocale.languageCode);

    if (!LocalizationManager.allLang.contains(locale)) return; //Not-existing Locale Safety

    var prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.setString('AppInfo_DefLocale', newlocale.languageCode);

    _prefLocale = newlocale;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```